# How to solve dependancy error on UWP xamarin Based application

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, uwp-xaml, windows-store, xamarin.uwp

I make new xamarin based app it build and works proper but when I try to build it works proper but when I try to publish it in Windows store i get this error on my x86 package but x64 package works proper.

I mention error here:

`The declared package dependency does not exist. Dependency: Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.Debug.2.0. Minimum version: 2.0.25709.0. Please upload the .msixupload or .appxupload file generated by Visual Studio for the Store.`

Can anyone have idea about this? Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to upload the Debug version of your app. During Store package creation you need to make sure to select `Release` for all configurations:

[image: Release selected]

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, there is no option `Release (x86)` for `x86` in `Release options` in my project. So, I use `Ad-Hoc (x64)` for `x64` & `Ad-Hoc (x86)` for `x86`. Please suggest me.

Comment: That is definitely weird. Please, try creating blank new project and see if it has the release configurations. It will be necessary to add them to your project

Comment: As per your guidelines I create new blank project in that I show release configuration but in my current project I am not. Can you please suggest me what should what I have to check in that?